# Project elements from Array of Arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am currently struggling with a search through an array of arrays within a JSON file that is imported into MongoDB compass. At the code below you can see the array "track" contains multiple other arrays. Now I want to get the 4th value of each of this arrays, for example, I want to get "load" from the first, "mouseover" from the second and so on...

```
{
"name":"nutzer1_50ms",
"ip":"::1",
"date":"Sat, 16 Dec 2017 21:53:19 +0100",
"screen":"1920x1080",
"window":"1920x966",
"document":"1024x786",
"track":[
[1513457569930,0,0,"load",""],
[1513457569953,79,229,"mouseover","p3"],
[1513457570274,79,228,"mousemove","p3"],
[1513457570280,79,226,"mousemove","p3"],
["end","end","end","end"]]
}
```

I would be very glad to get some help on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query.

[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map//) iterating over `track` values & [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt//) to project the 4th element from array.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "4th": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$track",
          "as": "track",
          "in": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$$track",
              3
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thx first of all, I'm trying to use this code but it won´t work :(

Comment: np. Can I see your query ? Which part is not working ?

Comment: I am taking this straight into MongDB Compass Filter:
{"$project": {"4th": {"$map": {"input": "$track","as": "track","in": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$$track",3]}}}}}

Comment: Query Filter seems like for a regular query. This is a aggregate query. Not sure where/how run aggregate query in compass.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, I need to get the data visualized there :)

Comment: when want to count the value for example "click" I am using:

db.mycollection123.aggregate([{"$project": {"4th": {"$map": {"input": "$track","as": "track","in": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$$track",3]}}}}},{$count: "mousemove"}]) 

but the response is always 1, ist the projection always returning 1 value?

Comment: This will count the no of documents in the final results and save the value in mousemove field. You have to match to find all the documents where the value is click followed by count. Something like `db.mycollection123.count({"fieldname":"click"})`